# Must declare the scalar variable "@bit", in stored procedure as output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have this procedure, but when it works perfect, without the two if's which are setting the output parameter @bit. When i try to execute proc p3, the following error occurs

`Must declare the scalar variable "@bit".`

Here is the code

```
create proc p3 @codP int, @codM int, @dela datetime, @panala datetime, @pret smallint, @bit bit output
as
begin
    declare @val smallint
    set @val = (select COUNT(*)
                from OferteSpeciale as OS
                where OS.codP = @codP and OS.codM = @codM and 
                        ((@panala >= OS.dela and @panala <= OS.panala)
                        or (@dela >= OS.dela and @dela <= OS.panala) or
                        (@dela <= OS.dela and @panala >= OS.panala)))
    print @val
    if (@val = 0)
        begin
            insert into OferteSpeciale (codP,codM,dela,panala,pret) values (@codP,@codM,@dela,@panala,@pret)
            declare @others smallint
            set @others = (select COUNT(*)
                         from Cataloage as c, OferteSpeciale as os
                         where ((c.codM = @codM and c.codP = @codP and c.pret < @pret) or
                            (os.codM = @codM and os.codP = @codP and os.pret < @pret)))
            if (@others > 0)
              set @bit = 0
            else
              set @bit = 1
        end
    else
      RAISERROR 50001 'There is already a special offer for that product, in that shop, between that dates'
end
declare @bit bit
exec p3 1, 3, '2013-04-15', '2013-04-15', 25, @bit output
```

Comment: edited :) , sorry it was a question mistake

Answer (score 2):

Just as a quick answer, you are missing a "GO" after declaring your stored proc, if I try running it as you've provided I get a different error that goes away if I add a GO to split the declaration from the execution.

```
end
GO
declare @bit bit
exec p3 1, 3, '2013-04-15', '2013-04-15', 25, @bit output
```

Obviously I had to remove the contents of the stored proc as I don't have those objects in my DB, but the issue seems to be around "@Bit"